# "Flip View" of ListViews for Windows8

Tags: javascript, html, listview, windows-8

I would like to create a "FlipView" of ListViews in Windows8 using JS and HTML.  That is, I would like a control that would display a ListView and when the user swips or scrolls, it would display the contents of a different ListView.  Is this possible?  If so, how?  Thanks for helping a Windows8 noob!

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to put a listview under flipview, was not successful. css classes used by both controls overlap (e.g. win-item). I found that items in the nested list view occupied the whole available space like flip view item. This behavior was happening because the win-container hosting the nested list view item, was sized like that. I could not set its (win-container) size explicitly to smaller size even after overriding it in css file.

It does not look like that list view will work nested under a flip view for css/html. If any one else has had success with this, do share your comments and code.

if anyone had tried it in c# using FlipView and nested GridView/ListView and had success, do mark a answer with code (will be interesting to know).

Comment: Yeah that is what I was afraid of.  Thanks for your input though.